# Calling SOAP web service in Symfony2

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, soap, wsdl

In my Symfony2 project I need to make a SOAP call to a WebService, So I have installed `besimple/soap-client` using composer and configured it like this:

parameters.yml:

soap_options:
  wsdl: wsdl/test.wsdl

In services.xml

```
<!-- Soap Client -->
<service id="project.test.soap.wrapper"
        class="Project\Test\Soap\SoapClientWrapper">
    <argument key="soap_options">%soap_options%</argument>
</service>
```

I then injected this service into one of my Dto/TestTemplate.php

Next i created a Repositories directory in my Soap directory created by `besimple/soap-client`, in this repository I added TestAttrebiutes.php file:

```
namespace Project\Test\Soap\Repositories;

class TestAttributes {

    public $agentID;
    public $sourceChannel;
    public $organisationName;

    public function __construct(
        $agentID,
        $sourceChannel,
        $organisationName,
    ){
        $this->$agentID = $agentID;
        $this->$sourceChannel = $sourceChannel;
        $this->$organisationName = $organisationName;
    }
}
```

SO now in my TestTemplate.php i would expect to do something like this:

```
$this->soap->__call(new FttpStatusAttributes(
    '100',
    'Web',
    'Ferrari'
), **ASKING FOR ATTRIBUTES);
```

but it is asking me to add attributes right after i add them, what am I doing wrong is it possible to do the way I am trying to do it..?

Answer (score 1):

This code might be the problem:

```
$this->$agentID = $agentID;
$this->$sourceChannel = $sourceChannel;
$this->$organisationName = $organisationName;
```

When you access `$this->$agentID`, you’re accessing a member of `$this` which has the value of `$agentID`. So e.g. if `$agentID` was, say, `john123`, your code would actually mean

```
$this->john123 = 'john123';
```

This is clearly not what you want. Your code should read:

```
$this->agentID = $agentID;
$this->sourceChannel = $sourceChannel;
$this->organisationName = $organisationName;
```

To be honest, I don’t know if that solves the problem, as your question is a bit vague, but this is definitely something you’ll want to fix.